# How can I made a mapbox map go to a specific direction through a web form?

Tags: mapbox

I need to do the following from a web form allow to the user to type an addres like:

123 street, Miami, Florida. And the mapbox map must go to that specific direction.

How can I do this?

The website is working with php.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [mapbox-gl-geocoder](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/) plug-in. It uses the Mapbox Geocoding API to find the geolocation of an address and then updates the map accordingly.

If you want driving directions to a given address, have a look at [mapbox-gl-directions](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-directions/) .

Depending on your app requirements, you can call the [Geocoding API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#search-for-places) directly: it will give you a geolocation match for the specified address and then you can update the map. You can try the Geocoding functionality in the [API playground](https://www.mapbox.com/api-playground/#/forward-geocoding/?_k=t7jug9).